# Docker entrypoint to run commands with different users in interactive mode

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sudo, docker-entrypoint, docker-in-docker

I have a custom image with docker installed (docker-in-docker). When running the image, the user needs to be `$USERNAME` (and not root). However the docker service required root to be started.

Getting docker to run as non-root seems to be overly complicated. So I have attempted to use `su` in the entry-point instead, which works, but it is not interactive.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# ... A lot of steps here to install stuff that are not really relevant to the problem.

COPY container-helpers/entrypoint.sh .
USER root
ENV ENTRYUSER $USERNAME
ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD "pulumi up"
```

And `entrypoint.sh` is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
service docker start
export ENV_PATH=$PATH
su $ENTRY_USER -lp <<EOSU
set -e
export PATH=$ENV_PATH
. $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
pulumi stack select -c dev
npx meteor-deploy stack configure default
$@ # Run given argument as a command
EOSU
```

I run it as:

```
$ docker run --env-file local.env --privileged -it meteor-deploy-leaderboard
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [ OK ] 
Logging in using access token from PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN
error: --yes must be passed in to proceed when running in non-interactive mode
```

Or, if you don't want to take pulumi's word for it:

```
$ docker run --env-file local.env --privileged -it meteor-deploy-leaderboard bash; echo "exited"
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [ OK ] 
Logging in using access token from PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN
exited
```

Any idea how I can pass on the tty to the su command properly?

Comment: So this is docker-in-docker situation, and you want to run docker inside as non-root?

Comment: You should generally run only one thing in a container.  If you really need DinD (do you?) then run `docker:dind` as one container, and your application in a second container (in whichever Docker makes more sense for you).  This also resolves your user situation, since you don't need to be both root and not-root.

Comment: I am using docker in docker for a CI situation. Testing a package for pulumi. Running this separately defeats the purpose of testing the package.

Comment: Also technically only running one thing is run on the container. It's just a very high level thing. It runs pulumi, which in turn runs docker and meteor.

Comment: `docker:dind` won't work because its based on alpine. I need a glibc compatible base.

Comment: @Niklas running docker as non-root, sounds very tricky if not impossible. I just want to run docker, by whatever means necessary. But the entrypoint needs to be non-root.